# Oracle how to add generated column to a select *

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, how do I add a generated column to my result-set? In other words, how do I do the following in Oracle:

```
SELECT (col4 * (col1+col2+col3) + 13) as gen1, *
  FROM table1
  WHERE col3 > 123
    AND col4 = 5
  ORDER BY col1, col2
```

This query works in MySQL and MSSQL. But for some reason, I can't get it to work with Oracle! Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work if you qualify the * with the table name (or the alias name if you use one)

```
SELECT (col4 * (col1+col2+col3) + 13) as gen1, table1.*
  FROM table1
  WHERE col3 > 123
    AND col4 = 5
  ORDER BY col1, col2
```

Comment: Hello Justin, can you please explain why adding table name would work? Is it due to some standard definition and oracle does does not support this implicitly OR is it entirely something else

Comment: @MuditSingal - Honestly, I'm not sure.  I haven't looked deeply enough at the SQL standard to know what it says with respect to the implicit definition of the `*` and whether other databases let you omit the table or alias name to comply with the standard or as an extension of the standard.  I would guess it's an extension that Oracle doesn't support but I don't know that.